# White Screen Problem from Waveshare 7 inch display model B + Raspberry Pi 3 B

Tags: display, touchscreen, screen, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye, raspberry-pi-os-bullseye-64

**The display:**

[7inch Capacitive Touch Screen LCD (B), 800×480, HDMI, Low Power](https://www.waveshare.com/7inch-hdmi-lcd-b.htm)

The **raspberries** I have:

[Raspberry Pi 3 Model B V1.2   2015 production](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-3-model-b/)

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)      /    aarch64

*And*

[Raspberry Pi Zero W V1.1    2017 production](https://www.raspberrypi.com/products/raspberry-pi-zero-w/)

OS: Debian GNU/Linux 11 (bullseye)     /   armv6l

**Tutorial:**

I followed this official [tutorial](https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/7inch_HDMI_LCD_(B)) from Waveshare.

**The issue**

is the screen remains in full white after powering on, nothing shows before the white, not within.

**What I've tried:**

Different HDMI cables, all of them tested on different screens and they work fine.

Different power supply connections, I tried from raspberries to the screen, and another try from a separate power supply.

Apt update, and apt full upgrade, and everything is perfectly up to date with no errors.

Not anything except the screen is attached to either of the raspberries.

Tried new OS images, formatted cards, even brand new cards, used the official app "Raspberry Pi Manager".

Tried different waveshare screen 4 Inch and it worked on both.

Tried different power supply sources, all 5V and between 2 and 3 amps.

**Config.txt** of the Raspberry **Pi 3** is:

```
display_auto_detect=1
max_framebuffers=2
arm_64bit=1
disable_overscan=1
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_cvt=800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_drive=1
```

**Config.txt** of the Raspberry **Zero W** is:

```
dtparam=audio=off
hdmi_force_hotplug=1
max_usb_current=1
config_hdmi_boost=15
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
max_usb_current=1
hdmi_mode=1
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 0
hdmi_timings=480 0 40 10 80 800 0 13 3 32 0 0 0 60 0 32000000 3
dtoverlay=ads7846,cs=1,penirq=25,penirq_pull=2,speed=50000,keep_vref_on=0,swapx>
hdmi_drive=1
dtparam=i2c_vc_baudrate=50000
disable_overscan=1
start_x=1
disable_splash=1
disable_fw_kms_setup=1
hdmi_ignore_cec_init=1
dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d
ignore_lcd=0
dtparam=audio=on
camera_auto_detect=1
display_auto_detect=1
max_framebuffers=2
disable_overscan=1
```

Any suggested solutions?
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Return it to the vendor for a refund??

Answer (score 0):

I have a 3.5 inch HDMI LED Waveshare display on a raspberry pi zero w running Bullseye 32 bit mode working fine with the following in /boot/config.txt. I am not using the touch part, only using it as a monitor.

```
# 3.5 inch HDMI LED Waveshare
# https://www.waveshare.com/wiki/3.5inch_HDMI_LCD
hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080
#Display with 800*480 resolution
hdmi_cvt 800 480 60 6 0 0 1
hdmi_group=2
hdmi_mode=87
hdmi_drive=2
hdmi_blanking=1
gpu_mem=32
```

The overlay `dtoverlay=vc4-fkms-v3d` caused problem for me, so I left it out. Also the EDID was not working correct, so `hdmi_ignore_edid=0xa5000080` took care of that.

```
$ cat /proc/fb; fbset

0 BCM2708 FB

mode "800x480"
    geometry 800 480 800 480 32
    timings 0 0 0 0 0 0 0
    rgba 8/16,8/8,8/0,8/24
endmode
```